# AWS CodePipeline not uploading all files into Artifacts and only deploys partially to Elastic Beanstalk. Missing js, css, png, files..etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, razor-pages, aws-codepipeline, cicd

Full Disclosure:  New to AWS but have some prev experience with Azure.

I would think that what I am trying to do is very common and can only assume I am just doing something wrong here. I've been experimenting for the past few weeks with using AWS CodePipleline to "CICD" my little sample .NET RazorPages app.

Everything runs fine locally. Static files such as css and js files load into page. In fact, can publish my RazorPages app directly to a ElasticBeanstalk instance using my AWS Toolkit in VS 2022. Again no problems.

[directly publishing from VS AWS Toolkit results img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efe1N.png)

However, things seems to go sideways when I use CodePipeline. Despite all my efforts, it seems the deploy process will not transfer over some of the files from my code repo (GitHub). More specifically, things located in the wwwroot folder.

http://jsplayground2021web-prod.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

[bad deploy - codepipleline forgets assets img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN889.png)

No errors from the source, build or deploy events in the pipeline. Nothing. The AWS CP reports success for the Source, Build, and Deploy stages.

I keep circling back to my buildspec.yml file (https://github.com/RedBirdOBX/JsPlayground2021/blob/master/buildspec.yml) but can't seem to get anything to be picked up in the files list.

Also, I have confirmed these files are in the not in the build artifact's zip file.

[missing assets in artifact in S3 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OupcL.png)

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Finding helpful tutorials has been a challenge. Pointers or assistance would be **appreciated**!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set files location like this:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```